# Use Zend_ACL to display list of users own posts

Tags: zend-framework, zend-acl

I have users and posts tables and I want to set it up so that a logged in user can only view his posts i.e created by him. The thing is that I know how this can be done with simple sql and php however I'm using a zend framework project here and I would like to know if this can be done using Zend_ACL and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Limit action access on certain resources/models can be done via Zend_Acl_Role, Zend_Acl_Resource and specificly Assertions using Zend_Acl_Assert_Interface, check out this page for more info:
http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.acl.advanced.html
and also this question [Zend Acl - is it possible for an assertion to allow access to a privilege when the acl rules return false?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5731449/zend-acl-is-it-possible-for-an-assertion-to-allow-access-to-a-privilege-when-t)

ACL wont select posts for you however it will allow/deny a user to edit/update/delete his own posts using assertions, this will only be done using SQL/Zend_Db, as you will have the list action for instance can be accessed by all users but the posts fetched in that action has nothing to do with ACL

Comment: Quick question though - then where would the logic go to decide what posts can be listed to the user?